why react component rendered as per profiler
I was working on a react project and wondering why a component is re-rendering and saw-

As per my knowledge react component re-rendering is fine but they shoudnt update on UI? am i right?
And when this profiler says rendered because parent rendered that means that the component will be re-rednered and will not be updated?
by re-rendering is fine but they shoudnt update on UI, I mean that component should not load on page!  on the DOM tree that component should not update and remain as it is

re-rendering is fine but they shoudnt update on UI? I'm not sure what you mean by this. Are you asking if it does the work of rerendering, but then throws out the result instead of updating the DOM?

I have updated the question with required details

Whether or not the DOM gets updated depends on what happens during that render. If the component returns exactly the same thing as last time, there are no updates to the DOM. If there are changes, those changes get pushed to the DOM. Does that answer your question?
